# Binding one button to two events with Tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I am just getting started with programming and am making a Tic-Tac-Toe program. In my program I have a display function, which changes and makes sure what entered is valid, and a win checker. Is there a way that I can bind both of these functions to the enter key?

Something like:

```
RowEnt.bind("<Return>", display, checkWin)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could nest both functions inside of another function :) for example:

```
def addone(num1):
    num1=int(num1)+1

def subtractone(num1):
    num1=int(num1)-1

def combine():
    addone(1)
    subtractone(1)
```

if you wanted to call both of them, you would simply use `combine()` as the function you call :)

Answer (score 23):

The key is passing `add="+"` when you bind the handler.  This tells the event dispatcher to add this handler to the  handler list.  Without this parameter, the new handler replaces the handler list.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tkinter # for Python 2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter # for Python 3

def on_click_1(e):
    print("First handler fired")

def on_click_2(e):
    print("Second handler fired")

tk = tkinter.Tk()
myButton = tkinter.Button(tk, text="Click Me!")
myButton.pack()

# this first add is not required in this example, but it's good form.
myButton.bind("<Button>", on_click_1, add="+")

# this add IS required for on_click_1 to remain in the handler list
myButton.bind("<Button>", on_click_2, add="+")

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is an ok solution for some widgets and events, but it's not a good solution for clicking on buttons. You should use the `command` attribute so you get the benefits of keyboard navigation, and a few other subtle things.

Comment: Good point about the keyboard bindings.  As far as I know, `command` will only take one function at a time, so IT Ninja's solution is good if you don't need to change the functions called much at runtime.  I'll post another solution which may be better if the list of called functions changes.

Comment: why isn't the add="+" option not documented?!.. it took me over an hour till I found your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here, only one function is called as a **direct** result of invoking the button (`invoke_mybutton`) and all it does is generates a virtual event `<<MyButton-Command>>>`.  This virtual event can be named anything as long as the name is not being used by Tk already.  Once that's in place, you can bind and unbind to `<<MyButton-Command>>>` using the `add='+'` option all day long and you'll get the benefits of keyboard bindings and such Bryan Oakley was referring to.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tkinter # for Python 2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter # for Python 3

def invoke_mybutton():
    tk.eval("event generate " + str(myButton) + " <<MyButton-Command>>")

def command_1(e):
    print("first fired")

def command_2(e):
    print("second fired")

tk = tkinter.Tk()
myButton = tkinter.Button(tk, text="Click Me!", command=invoke_mybutton)
myButton.pack()
myButton.bind("<<MyButton-Command>>", command_1, add="+")
myButton.bind("<<MyButton-Command>>", command_2, add="+")
tk.mainloop()
```