# Why don't ButtonPress and Button-1 execute together?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I wrote a very simple logic:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: print('b-1'), add='+')
root.bind('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: print('some button'), add='+')
root.mainloop()
```

I expect that when I click "`Button-1`", it should print "b-1" and "some button" (in some order). In practice it only prints "b-1". it looks like `bind('<Button-1>', …)` overrides another bind. I can't really figure out why.

Question: Why does this happen and how to fix this?

P.S. I am pretty sure that this question might be a duplicate due to its simplicity, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: what is `add=`? I don't think if there is any such attributes in binding function.

Comment: @SuramuthuR this parameter has been present in tkinter for decades. Information about it can be found in the Internet, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881534/binding-one-button-to-two-events-with-tkinter/11525596#11525596)

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this in this way? For what it's worth, when I middle- or right-click, `'some button'` is printed. So it seems like only the left-click binding is being overridden by the initial binding to `'<Button-1>'`

Comment: I never worked out how multiple `tkinter` bindings work. Can you make a function for button press and another for button release? And then you can simulate the behaviour of button-1

Comment: @JRiggles I just want to make one function that will used for all buttonPress events (special function for managment) and other functions for binding (such as for button 1). I know I can write 5 bindings, like `bind(button-1, some_f)`, `bind(button-2, some_f)` and etc. But in my opinion this makes the code a bit uglier.

Comment: @TheLizzard do you mean create one function for ButtonPress and then in it do a check for the button pressed (e.g., if Button_1, call another function)? Might work, but it makes an "unsafe" class. There's nothing stopping you from mistakenly writing a binding that breaks the logic. With this feature I need to block other binding, so create new functions for bindings and so on… There is no point, in this case it is faster (and safer) to just write separate bindings.

Comment: @DanyaK, What do you mean by 'all buttons' ? Do you mean all buttons together? If you mention that, I can give you my answer. If that is not the case, I've given answers for all the possibilities of your question.

Comment: The reason this is happening is because the most specific binding will be executed. This is possible to do with some limitations and require expertise in some features. I can't see what would require such complicated code. Can you elaborate on what you really want to achieve here?

Comment: @Thingamabobs you can find an explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78048953/why-dont-buttonpress-and-button-1-execute-together?noredirect=1#comment137596124_78048953) comment

Comment: Is there a group of `Button` you want to bind to?

Comment: Please join the [tkinter chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Per OP:

> I just want to make one function that will used for all buttonPress events

Since the `'<ButtonPress>'` (or `'<Button>'`) binding handles all three mouse clicks, you can simply bind a callback that handles the event accordingly, as the button number will be passed in via the passed `event`

```
import tkinter as tk


def button_handler(event) -> None:
    match event.num:
        case 1:
            print('Left Click')
        case 2:
            print('Middle Click')  # right click on Mac OS
        case 3:
            print('Right Click')  # middle click on Mac OS
        case _:  # fallback case
            raise NotImplementedError


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<ButtonPress>', button_handler)
root.mainloop()
```

Naturally, you can put whatever code you want into each `case`, including calls to other functions

NB: the use of `match:case` assumes you're using Python 3.10 or later

Comment: This will work, but will bring some problems. I already mentioned them in my comment to TheLizzard [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78048953/why-dont-buttonpress-and-button-1-execute-together/78049528#comment137596263_78048953)

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the confusion. See my edited answer. Change `<ButtonPress>` to `<Button>`. Then it works alright. [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/Ow9qLLY)

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: print('b-1'), add='+')
root.bind('<Button>', lambda e: print('some button'), add='+')
root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
The above code will execute in following way:
If you click left_key in mouse, it will print 'b-1'
If you click any other button except left-key in mouse, it'll print 'some button'.
After seeing your comment, I understood like this: when you click left-key in mouse, it should print 'b-1', but only the first time. After pressing left-button once, if you click any button in the mouse - even if it is left-key, it should print 'some button'. If this is your requirement, the following is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk

def first_click(evnt):
    print('b-1')
    root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e:'break')
    root.bind('<Button-1>',any_button)
    
def any_button(evnt): print('some button')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.bind('<Button-1>', first_click)
root.bind('<Button>', any_button)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well this definitely works, but I need to make two bindings, one for Button-1 and one for Button (ButtonPress), not for key

Comment: I can still only get this to print `'b-1'`

Comment: Ok. I assume this way. When the user leftclicks first time it should print b-1. From second time onwards, if the user clicks any button in mouse it should print 'some button'. Is this what you want? I can cahange the code accordingly

Comment: @DanyaK, I've made a second edit. Kindly confirm whether this is what you want. The confusion arises because While pressing any button in the mouse, you haven't clarified whether the any button includes left key. Any way, I've given code for both.